# Html, Javascript, or Css cloud sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to create a slide effect similar to the clouds on this page: http://www.poweredwebsite.com/index-v.php

Using javascript (JQuery), css, or html.
My current code is not working (I am using Chrome)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .images-container {
            position: absolute;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        function animate() {
            $(".scroll-image").animate({ "left": "+=500px" }, 3000, "linear",
                                   function () {
                                       $(this).css({ "left": "-=500px" });
                                       animate();
                                   });
        }

        animate();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <span class="images-container">
            <span class="scroll-image" style="left: -500px">
                <img src="http://www.startextures.com/starnetblog/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/starnetblog_seamless_hazard_danger_texture4.jpg" width="500px">
            </span>
            <span class="scroll-image" style="left: 0px">
                <img src="http://www.startextures.com/starnetblog/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/starnetblog_seamless_hazard_danger_texture4.jpg" width="500px">
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

**Markup**:

```
<div class="bg"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bg {
    background: url(http://www.startextures.com/starnetblog/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/starnetblog_seamless_hazard_danger_texture4.jpg) center top;
    height: 700px;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
var bgPos = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    $(".bg").css("background-position", (bgPos-= 1) + "px");
}, 60);
```

It should look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2Fb3p/

Play around with the `setInterval` time, and the amount of pixels you move it, until you get the desired effect.

Comment: Simple & efficient. Nice to look at :) On the website shown as example by OP, it does totally lag out my console though

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="images-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.images-container {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://www.startextures.com/starnetblog/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/starnetblog_seamless_hazard_danger_texture4.jpg");
    background-position: 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function animate() {
    $(".images-container").animate({"background-position": "-=5"}, 200, "linear")
}

setInterval(animate, 200)
```

Use `animate(...,...,linear)` then the animation doesn't jumping